# Loading bar in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have been doing Google search for the past two days and couldn't find what I want.

I have SMSmobile tool being developed in PHP which allow client to send Bulk SMS, when the my clients press `Send` button the browser will keep loading until the SMS been sent to all of his contacts (it might be 100000 contacts or more) so it will take from 2-5 minutes. In the mean while if the client press browser `Refresh`button or any other button from the same page it will destroy the sending process.

I need to display a pop-up progress bar that prevent the user from doing any action until the `Sending` process is over.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you show some code of how you're currently doing it?  One suggestion could be to not make the actual SMS sending an in-process activity.  Queue up the messages in a database and have a back-end process send them.  That way the user can continue to interact with the site.  Then the site could maybe have a progress indicator of some kind on each page.  This would be particularly good if the process can take a long time (more than a minute).

Comment: I would suggest using AJAX, and web sockets to report back progress. Also, just because the person refreshes the page, doesn't necessarily have to kill the server side PHP process that is running the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkRefresh()
{
if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "" )
{

    document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";


}
else
{
document.write ('
$(function2() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: 59
    });
});
')
}
}
```

Make sure you have jQuery!

MarkUp:

```
<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
<div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then replace your body tag with this:

```
<body onLoad="JavaScript:checkRefresh();">
```

And add this to your HTML:

```
<form name="refreshForm">
<input type="hidden" name="visited" value="" />
</form>
```

Anyway, this detects a reload and executes a loading bar, which will prevent them from reloading (hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

Use a lock of some sort, even a file lock. Then using ajax to poll every X seconds to see if the job is finished or not.

```
function send() {
   if ( file_exists('/tmp/' . $session_key . '.lck' ) ) return;
   touch ( '/tmp/' . $session_key . '.lck' );
   # do the actual job
   # ...
   unlink( '/tmp/' . $session_key . '.lck' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be a background running script (cron job) that just stands there reading a kind of Queue list (SQL Table) and proceed all the new entries it sees.

Maybe a small client-side scripts that calls something behind that just count the rows and returns it to the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on having this happen in the page, I would suggest combining a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) with an [animated progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated).

You don't even have to do any calculations on the progress bar, just set it at 100%, so it looks like it's scrolling, and add some text like, "Your messages are being processed."

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not just `loading bar` a `lot of things are wrong with your application architecture`

Question ?  `Even if the person does not click refresh and there is a connection issue what happens`

**Quick Solution**

Take the `SMS information`

Store in `Database`

Send Later use `cron JOB`

**Better Solution**

Use `Messaging Queue`

You don't have to show a loading bar on the users phone .... `Message Sent` would be a better option

Thanks

:)